# Сортировка массива (пузырёк) на JS, необходимо перебрать код используя map()

Tags: javascript

Прохожу стажировку и сегодня выполнял задание по сортировке массива пузырёк. Написал след. код :

```
const sortArr = (arr) => {
  let unit;
  for (let i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    for (let b = 0; b < i; b++) {
      if (arr[b] > arr[b + 1]) {
        unit = arr[b];
        arr[b] = arr[b + 1];
        arr[b + 1] = unit;
      }
    }
  } 
  return arr;
};
```

К слову сказать самостоятельно не додумался запутался во вложенном цикле, однако перечитав разные топики по данной сортировке взял из разных мест идеи и реализацию и по памяти продумывая каждый шаг изобразил данный код.

Далее внёс изменения по указанию наставника и сделал с циклом while. И вот следующая задача была сделать с использованием "других циклов" я уточнил каких именно? - на что получил ответ - ".map ..." загуглив нашёл метод map() который применяет функцию к каждому элементу массива, сижу вот думаю и ничего не приходит в голову, подскажите или хотя бы направьте в нужном направлении чтобы мне удалось реализовать поставленную задачу и разобраться, думаю, что возможно речь вообще не об этом методе, просто я не совсем понимаю, что значит указание наставника.

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/array-iteration

Comment: @Alexander Chernin, к чему эта статья? Он спросит как отсортировать массив с помощью map, а не другими методами. В ней ничего по вопросу нет

Comment: Да, спасибо Владислав, я читал эту статью и пример в конце смотрел, к сожалению до меня не доходит как можно используя этот метод, изменить функцию и убрать циклы или же что вообще можно сделать, как она мне тут может пригодиться в использовании..

Comment: @ВладиславЖидко там есть про map. Если он имея код и логику сортировки не понимает как применить map, значит он не понимает тот код который уже имеет и объяснять использование map бессмысленно

Comment: @Mark вам надо еще раз подумать на тем кодом и методом сортировки, который у вас уже есть и разобраться в них. Потом уже посмотреть на map и потом вы уже сами поймете, что надо сделать. Сделать за вас не трудно, но вам это ничего не даст, надо самому

Comment: @Alexander Chernin, я так понимаю ему for'ы и if'ы надо заменить map.  Сами справитесь ?

Comment: Код, который я указал я написал сам прочитав разные материалы и примеры по данной сортировке, и в этом коде я прекрастно понимаю каждый шаг, что происходит и почему. Однако мне не ясно где я могу применить map(). Если я верно понял данный метод, он берёт элемент массива и применяет к нему функцию возвращая результат в новый массив, как в примере, но как данный функционал применить тут и собственно заменив "что" на данный функционал? Вот тут у меня и возникает проблема понимания.

Comment: Давайте я попробую. Цикл `for` пробегает по каждому элементу массива. Метод `forEach` делает то же самое. Цикл `for` можно заменить на метод `forEach`, в свою очередь `forEach`, можно заменить на `map`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, вот только нафига?

Comment: @Qwertiy а вот это я хз. Может, в этом есть некий сакральный смысл, который ускользает от меня.

Comment: https://reactgo.com/bubble-sort-algorithm-javascript/